# Choose between search and "I'm feeling lucky" at location bar

Tags: firefox, google-search, awesomebar, feeling-lucky

Normally when I type something that isn't a URL into the address bar I want to search for it, but sometimes I want to go straight to the site. Is there a way I can set Firefox up to do this?

I'd prefer a keyboard-only solution like "type '/' in front when you want *I'm feeling lucky*" or "use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for *I'm feeling lucky*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the search box when you want to do a regular search and the address box when you want to do IFL searches?

If you don't want to do that, there is a method to create custom awesomebar shortcuts.  You do it by creating a bookmark with a url that contains `%s` where you want the query to go, then setting a custom keyword for it.

For example:

1. Create a new bookmark, set the "location" attribute to "http://google.com/search?q=%s"
2. Set a keyword for it (e.g. 'g' or 'google')
3. Save it

Then you could do something like `g wikipedia` in the address bar to google Wikipedia, or just type `wikipedia` when you want to do an "I'm feeling lucky" search.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, make this as your new search engine:

http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=Im+Feeling+Lucky

It works nice in Opera and Chrome too :)

Comment: This would be accepted answer.

Comment: This shows a forwarding note from google..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but for the same purpose I like to use the DuckDuckGo as default for its syntax. Searching for "! foo" uses *I'm feeling Ducky* (heh) so I don't have to select a different engine from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Directing unresolved addresses to lucky:

`about:config` → `keyword.URL` → `http://google.com/search?btnI&q=`